# how to prove that there is no arbitrage if the following inequality is satisfied?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, finance

The continuously compounded interest rate is $r$. The current price of the underlying asset is $S(0)$, and the forward price with delivery time in one year is $F(0,1)$. Short selling of the stock requires a security deposit in the amount of $fS(0)$ for some $f∈(0,1)$. Assume that the security deposit earns an interest $d$ that is compounded continuously. Prove that there is an arbitrage opportunity if the following inequality is satisfied
$$d \gt ln\left(e^r-\frac{e^rS(0)-F(0, 1)}{fS(0)}\right)$$

I am not entirely sure of what I have to do here, I know I have to show that the price in one year after interest is less than the current price $S(0)$, but I don't know how to do that?
Do I get $F(0, 1)$ alone on one side of the inequality?

Comment: When you say that "the security deposit incurs an interest dd" do you mean "the security deposit earns interest at a rate of d"?

Comment: @lulu thank you, that was a typo

Comment: No arbitrage iff $(0<)d< 1 + r<u$ [right](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-BLM.pdf)? perhaps just follow proof of what happens when $(0<)1+r \le d <u$ ?

Comment: Also I'd change the title (as the inequality does not imply no-arbitrage).  And I'd still change the verb "incurs"  which sounds like a bad thing.  The deposit "earns" interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only trade we have to look at is:  buy the forward position at the forward rate and short the position through to the forward date.  "arbitrage free" would require that this be a zero-sum.

To achieve the short position I sell the stock today, netting $S(0)$.  I then invest the proceeds at $r$.  I also must borrow $fS(0)$ at $r$, but at least I earn $d$ on it.  Thus arbitrage-free implies $$F(0,1)=e^rS(0)-e^rfS(0)+e^dfS(0)$$  rearranging this says that $$e^d=e^r -\frac {e^rS(0)-F(0,1)}{fS(0)}$$

From which the desired claim follows.

Comment: doesn't $F(0,1)=e^rS(0)-e^rfS(0)+e^dfS(0)$ tell us the final amount at time $1$? The reason that we know that there is no arbitrage is becasue it rearanges to the given inequality?

Comment: The "no arbitrage" condition means that the two ways of computing the forward have to give the same value.  If $d$ is larger then then value implicit in that equation, then there is an arbitrage.